# Is there a lsqcurvefit equivalent in java?

Tags: java, matlab, curve-fitting

Or any other function that could take several pairs as input and output the fitted curve or function in the format you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [linear algebra](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/linear.html) and [optimization](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/optimization.html) functionality of the Apache Commons Math library. You probably want something that implements the `DecompositionSolver` interface.

Comment: I have skimmed the source. Nice one to do linear fit. Thanks a lot. 
But have you heard any lib that could do non-linear fit?

Comment: Apache Commons can; see the [optimization](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/optimization.html) link I gave above. Unlike the linear algebra stuff, it is not specific to linear least squares.

Comment: It worked. It is exactly what I am seeking for. Thanks a lot for helping  @Joshua Barr

Comment: No problem. If it was useful, can you accept one of the answers (Matthew's or mine)?

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/) from Apache Commons.

The Statistics package has a Class called [SimpleRegression](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/stat.html#a1.4_Simple_regression) that may be helpful to you.

Comment: Good information, but I think `SimpleRegression` is most similar to using `polyfit` to do linear regression in matlab. I think he wants something a little more general (see below).

Comment: Nice suggestion. I have Looked it up and found it is a good package to do linear regression, but is there any package for non-linear regression?

Comment: @Huayi Guo. You can try this code: [Michael Thomas Flanagan's Java Scientific Library](http://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~mflanaga/java/Regression.html). It worked well, but could not use because of the license agreement.